# Hyperlink popup message based on column value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have the jquery grid columns like below.

```
colNames: ['Site_Name', 'Details'],
colModel: [{ name: 'Site_Name', index: 'Site_Name', width: 130,editable: false,
sortable: false,formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: { 
baseLinkUrl: 'javascript:', showAction: "Link('", addParam: "');"} },
{ name: 'Details', index: 'Details', width: 400, editable: false, sortable: false }],
```

Hyperlink is formed for a column.

once the user clicks on that hyperlink based values in another column (let's say status of that record/row).
I need to display a popup message before navigating to the actual page.

How can I write a click event on a custom formatted hyperlink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I can see once user clicks the hyperlink then function Link() is called.
So the Link() function is the place where you can show the popup message before navigating to the url.